# Summing cells across variable sets of sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook with 30+ sheets each containing an identical template for financial data for a unique entity. Each entity is designated as either in the Owned, Managed, or Facilities portfolios. The portfolio designation exists on each template in A3, as well as on a reference data sheet that contains a list of the sheet names in column 1 and their assigned portfolios in column 2.

I also have a Summary sheet with an identical template. This is where my issue is.

I want to be able to sum the individual cells across other sheets variably based on a drop down of the 3 portfolios. For example, if you select "Managed," I want the template to fill in with the sum of all the managed sheets, "Owned," the same, etc.

I messed with 3D sumifs, and it's something I've employed elsewhere in the template, but for this sheet I can't figure out how to get it to only sum the values in the tabs that meet the criteria. I want it to be something easy like Sumif(SheetStart:SheetEnd!G12,Sheetstart:SheetEnd!A3,D3), but it's obviously not that simple. I haven't gotten enough of the formula to function to be worth mentioning.

I'm on version 2207 (Office 365).
Example of the summary tab:
[image: Example of the summary tab]

Comment: This is going to be super easy if you can arrange the portfolio sheets in order, for instance all the “owned” tabs are together, then all the “managed” tabs.  Otherwise, using the data in your reference sheet may require using a very large number of INDIRECT functions and being a volatile function, that has performance implications at scale.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT function? https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function#:~:text=The%20SUMPRODUCT%20function%20multiplies%20arrays%20together%20and%20returns,it%20may%20seem%20boring%2C%20complex%2C%20and%20even%20pointless.

Comment: @Max 
Performance is out the window on this thing. The templates in the other 30 tabs are autofilled using Sumif/Indirect functions, so I have 12k other cells ruining that pipe dream already, so I'm not so worried about adding more to a single additional template. Yes, I could just group the tabs, but ideally I'd like to keep them in order of Dept # if possible.

Comment: I don't have "an answer" yet but here's what I am thinking approach-wise.  You are going to have a "Portfolio" array that is all 30x sheet's A3 values, in sheet order.  For each value you want to sum (like G12) you'll create an array that is all 30 G12 values, in the same order.  Then SUMIF, SUMPRODUCT, or FILTER are all available to you to as ways to determine which of the 30 values to sum, based on whether D3 matches the Portfolio array.  Because you are grabbing a value from ALL 30+ sheets, there's no need to use INDIRECT.  You get them all and then apply logic.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what I have come up with that I think does what you want to do.  Had to build a test sheet first to make sure this approach worked.

- Assume the selector criteria dropdown is in local cell D3
- Assume each sheet's portfolio identifier is in A3
- Assume all the tabs value cells align, including the summation page, meaning the formula on the summation page in G12 is the sum of the G12s on the correct detail pages.
- Assume the data pages are contiguous but no need to be sorted in any order.

Then place this formula in summation page G12, and fill down/right.  The G12 reference should increment as needed.

```
=LET(
portfolioArray, --($D$3=VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet4!$A$3)),
valueArray, VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet4!G12),
SUMPRODUCT(valueArray,portfolioArray)
)
```

- This creates an array "valueArray" that is all 30+ values for each cell.
- This creates an array "portfolioArray" that is 30+ 1's and 0's, with the 1's representing which tab's A3 values matched the selector.
- Then sumproduct the two arrays, that should both be the same 30+:1 dimension.

I put this in a LET for easier following, but it could as easily have been:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet4!G12),--($D$3=VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet4!$A$3)))
```

**Edit:** But as I mentioned in my comment, this could just as easily be:

```
=SUMIF(VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet4!$A$3), $D$3, VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet4!G12) )
```

My next effort was going to be to put this in a LET(MAKAEARRAY( )) model so that the portfolio array is only ever calculated once, but that will take more fiddling.

I *really* wanted to avoid the INDIRECT overhead so my idea was to gather ALL 30 datapoints and filter them with logic, rather than using logic to create a sequence of references to the desired sheets that would each be pulled in via INDIRECT.

Hope this helps!